# JsonRpc request from ios 12 sends empty content

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, json-rpc, capacitor

I am using vue-json-rpc-client-fetch-withcredentials for comunication with my api via jsonRpc in my ionic5/vue project. Comunication works fine in browser and ios 13 (devices and simulators), but when i running app on ios 12, request’s response is "Invalid request". The reason of invalid request is, that reguest’s content is empty. Does anyone know why? I am using Capacitor to create ios version. I tried to create request with another ways, but i have still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed setting for headers on API server and it's working now. So, it's really the difference between

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');`

and

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");`